# Keep the current locale after invalidating a session with JSF

Tags: jsf

This method invalidates the session and gets the user back to the home page.

```
public String restart() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
    return "/index?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

As a consequence, the locale chosen by the user is forgotten and the app switches back to the default locale of the browser. **I want that the locale remains the same even after the session invalidation**. The method now looks like:

```
public String restart() {
    Locale currLocale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestLocale();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(currLocale);

    return "/index?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

But the locale still switches back to the browser's default. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: How about adding a request parameter to the URL you are redirecting to?

Comment: oh good point, all the more than I planned to add this at some point for easier language-aware bookmarks. I am still curious about the bean-side solution :-)